# How to check if div is inside another div -not only with small size but inside it

Tags: jquery, html, position

I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to check if a div in inside another div. I need not only second div to be smaller than first but also to be in its containment.
How to do that?
I tried with this but it checks only if size of second div is smaller than first div's size:

```html
if($('#div1').height() <= 375 || $('#div1').width() <= 500 ) {
```

Edited:

```js
  $(function() {
        
        
        $('body').on('click', '.save', function(){
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            $( ".bomb-overlay-holder" ).html('<img id="bomb-overlay">');
            $('.bomb-overlay-holder > img').attr('src',src);
            $( ".bomb-overlay-holder" ).draggable({ containment: ".background-bomb" });
            $( "#bomb-overlay" ).resizable({autoHide: true,});
            $( "#bomb-overlay" ).parent().rotatable({autoHide: true,});

        });
```

My first div is `.background-bomb` and my second div is `#bomb-overlay`.

Comment: _div in inside another div_ Do mean `div1` is child of `div2`?

Comment: I mean I have 2 pictures and I set second picture inside first picture and when user saves it, second picture should not be outside from first. User should first resize second pic, so that it is inside first pic.

Comment: can you create a problem fiddle?

Comment: If I understand correctly take a look at http://api.jquery.com/offset/. Find there `offsets` and compare for checking if `div2` is in the containment of `div1`

Comment: If I see coordinates of first div, how to check second div is in its containment? Thanks :)

Comment: you need to atleast provide some `html`

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking the `containement` part

```
    var div1 = $('#div1');
    var div2 = $('#div2');
    var offset1 = div1.offset();
    var offset2 = div2.offset();
    var right1 = offset1.left + div1.width();
    var bottom1 = offset1.top + div1.height();
    var right2 = offset2.left + div2.width();
    var bottom2 = offset2.top + div2.height();

    //Now you can do something like...
    if(offset1.left <= offset2.left && offset1.top <= offset2.top && right1 >= right2 && bottom1 >= bottom2) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you all! I have to learn jquery and javascript. I'm just beginner. :)